# Get UICollectionView height inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView inside a scrollview which has cell with dynamic width and static height.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return tagArray.count;

}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TagsCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"tagsCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath ];
    [cell bindWithModel:tagArray[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize yourLabelSize = [tagArray[indexPath.row] sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];

    return CGSizeMake(yourLabelSize.width+20+40, 40);

}
```

I could calculate height using :

```
CGFloat height = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height;
```

[image]I am getting higher value than actual height.

Answer (score 1):

```
collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
```

Asks the delegate for the size of the specified item’s cell.

```
CGFloat height = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

This will return the collectionView height not the collectionView Cell's height.

Comment: I didn't get you.

Comment: CollectionView height is different from a single collectionviewcell's height. The delegate method used here is to return the size of collectionviewcell.

Comment: I assume you were comparing your static cell height(40) with collectionViewContentSize.height.

Comment: No, i was finding height using self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height, not delegate

Comment: That is what I am saying. This method is used to find out collectionviewheight which may include header and footer plus collectionviewcell height. In your case collectionviewcell height is 40 which is passed in delegate. Probably you understand what I am saying now?

Comment: Yes. How can i find collection view height in this case?

Comment: I think you are correctly calculating the collection view contentsize's height. If you want the collection view frame size's height, use frame.size.height on collection view. By the way I don't understand what you want to calculate.

Comment: I think he is asking how to get height which exactly fits his all cells inside. You may have to add each cell in row height and add some padding to get that.

Comment: i need exact height of collectionview because it is inside a scrollview. Number of cell is dynamic and width of cell is dynamic.